# Compare lists with other lists for elements in preserved order

Tags: python

I have a few lists of words. Some of the lists share common words with each other. I'm trying see for each list, what other list has the common words in the same sequence. For example lets say these are my lists (using letters instead of words/strings for simplicity):

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d]
list2 = [f,n,a,b,g]
list3 = [x,f,g,z]
list4 = [y,a,b,f,g,k]
```

Over here we can see that [a,b] from list1 is also present in that order in list2 and list4. We can also see that [f,g] from list3 is present in list4. So we will map these lists to each other as follows:

```
list1: list2, list4 #(contains [a,b])
list2: list1, list4 #(contains [a,b])
list3: list4 #(contains [f,g])
list4: list1, list2, list3 #(contains [a,b] and [f,g])
```

You can ignore the comments since that's for explanation, it will be just the list names mapped to each other. Note that even though list2 has the elements 'f' and 'g', since they are not in the order [f,g] it does not map to list3 or list4.

I have written a function using set.intersection() to get the common words across all my lists, but it does not care for the order. So, I cant seem to figure out which data structure or algorithm to use in order to map the lists to each other in that fashion.

I was trying the following, where wordlists is my list of lists, each containing their respective amount of words:

```
filelist = {}
for i in range(0, len(wordlists)):
    current_wordlist = wordlists[i]
    for j, j_word in enumerate(current_wordlist):
        if current_wordlist[j] == j_word:
            if j_word not in filelist:
                filelist[i] = {j}
            else:
                filelist[i].append(j)
```

But it does not map correctly since its not mapping to the correct list number. I would appreciate some feedback or some other trick of checking this.

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would create a helper that creates sets of successive items for each list:

```
def create_successive_items(lst, n):
    return set(zip(*[lst[i:] for i in range(n)]))
```

Then you can simply check the intersection for all lists based on these sets:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['f','n','a','b','g']
list3 = ['x','f','g','z']
list4 = ['y','a','b','f','g','k']


lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

# First look for two elements
i = 2

all_found = []

while True:
    # find all "i" successive items in each list as sets
    succ = [create_successive_items(lst, i) for lst in lists]
    founds = []
    # Check for matches in different lists
    for list_number1, successives1 in enumerate(succ, 1):
        # one only needs to check all remaining other lists so slice the first ones away
        for list_number2, successives2 in enumerate(succ[list_number1:], list_number1+1):
            # Find matches in the sets with intersection
            inters = successives1.intersection(successives2)
            # Print and save them
            if inters:
                founds.append((inters, list_number1, list_number2))
                print(list_number1, list_number2, inters)

    # If we found matches look for "i+1" successive items that match in the lists
    # One could also discard lists that didn't have "i" matches, but that makes it
    # much more complicated.
    if founds:
        i += 1
        all_found.append(founds)
    # no new found, just end it
    else:  
        break
```

This prints the matches:

```
1 2 {('a', 'b')}
1 4 {('a', 'b')}
2 4 {('a', 'b')}
3 4 {('f', 'g')}
```

and these are also avaiable in `all_founds` and can be used and/or converted, i.e. converted to a `dict`:

```
matches = {}
for match, idx1, idx2 in all_found[0]:
    matches.setdefault(idx1, []).append(idx2)
    matches.setdefault(idx2, []).append(idx1)

>>> matches
{1: [2, 4], 
 2: [1, 4], 
 3: [4], 
 4: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Couldn't we declare all_founds as a dict and have it map the values too? Like 1 -> 2, 4; 2 -> 4; 3->4, 4->1,2,3?

Comment: that wouldn't be a problem but the answer already got quite long so I didn't want to include more logic than necessary. You can always manipulate the `all_founds` after the function. Should I show how or would you like to do it yourself?

Comment: I think I got it, I was just having trouble checking it to see if order is preserved. Most forms of intersect don't take order into account and I wasn't sure if such a function existed in list or set. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can have some fun by using sets of tuples.  Because tuples are hashable all you need are a couple of helper functions to get you all successive ordered sublists from a given list and you can compare using set intersection.

```
from itertools import permutations
def radix(rg, n_len):
    """
    Returns all ordered sublists of length n_len from
    the list rg
    :type rg: list[char]
    :type n_len: int
    """
    for x in range(0, len(rg) - n_len + 1):
        yield tuple(rg[x:x + n_len])

def all_radixes(rg):
    """
    Returns all ordered sublists of length 2 or longer
    from the given list
    :type rg: list[char]
    """
    for x in range(2, len(rg) + 1):
        for result in radix(rg, x):
            yield result

def compare_lists(rg1, rg2):
    s1 = set(all_radixes(rg1))
    s2 = set(all_radixes(rg2))
    return s1 & s2

list1 = 'a,b,c,d'.split(',')
list2 = 'f,n,a,b,g'.split(',')
list3 = 'x,f,g,z'.split(',')
list4 = 'y,a,b,f,g,k'.split(',')

all_lists = [ list1, list2, list3, list4 ]
for z in permutations(all_lists, 2):
    print 'Intersection of %s and %s: %s' % (z[0], z[1], compare_lists(z[0], z[1]),)
```

Comment: btw: `set(x for x in all_radixes(rg1))` is the identical to `set(all_radixes(rg1))`

Comment: Right you are.  Thank you.